# Determine the position of the view port scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I am using [Addazle React grid](https://github.com/adazzle/react-data-grid). I need to implement endless scrolling, but that grid does not have it implemented. So I have to come up with my solution.
For the task I need to know the following:

- Grid on scroll event handler. I have it and it fires properly.
- Find out position of the scroll bar on the React element. I need to figure out how to do that.

My idea is to find out the position of the scroll bar, and if it the last one, then load more items in the grid. I am thinking to use JQuery for the task.
This is the html that is rendered:

```
<div class="react-grid-Viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute;" data-reactid="1"> <div style="position: absolute;overflow-x: auto;overflow-y: scroll; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
 <div style="width:1040px;overflow:hidden;">          
      <!--Items in the grid are stored here as divs-->
      <!--Item One-->
      <div style="background-color:#fff;">
          <div>

          </div>
      </div>
      <!--Item Two-->
      <div style="background-color:#fff;">
          <div>

          </div>
      </div>
       <!--Item t-->
      <div style="background-color:#fff;">
          <div>

          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the scrollbar is the last one when you have scrolled to the bottom, that is no more scrolling is available. We first need to store the maximum scrollable amount in a variable as:

```
var maxscroll = $(".react-grid-viewport").height() - $(".react-grid-viewport > div").eq(0).height();
```

Now you can use the condition that when `scrollTop` of the container div becomes equal to the maxscrollable amount then load more items from the back end as:

```
$(".react-grid-viewport").scroll(function(){
   var maxscroll = $(".react-grid-viewport").height() - $(".react-grid-viewport > div").eq(0).height();

  if($(this).scrollTop() == maxscroll) {
    console.log("Load the next 10 items from the back end");
  }

});
```

Comment: Strange.
When I run:
var maxscroll = $(".react-grid-Viewport").height() - $(".react-grid-Viewport > div").eq(0).height();
It always gives -1

Comment: @Wexoni you absolute positiong is messing things up. Try giving fixed height to `react-grid-viewport`

Comment: I will give it a try :)